# What is the name of this Idle Mixture Screw Plug?

Tags: carburetor, idle

My car is a 1987 Toyota Tercel DX Wagon 1452cc 2bl manual driven car. Carburetor of it is a Aisan 14120 Two Barrel carburetor.

I have disassembled my Carburetor for repair.

Idle Mixture Screw lies in a "Special plug" that I have never seen before. That plug has a orifice at the end for the upper Idle opening. Idle screw lies inclined angle at the mid part.

[image: Photo1]

[image: photo2]

Carburetor has separate holes for Idle Mixture Screw and for this plug.

[image: Photo3]

[image: photo 4]

I want to know the name of this plug to order a new one for replace (Old one is damaged). Manual doesn't provide any name or any indication even.

Can anyone tell me the name of this plug?

Comment: I would suggest anti-vibration plug, but I understood from your other post that you knew all the names : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/46676/what-is-this-part-of-my-carburetor-and-what-does-it-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Anti-Vibration Plug

This is called "Anti-Vibration Plug". This plug is to prevent adjustment of the idle jet for emissions reasons, which is factory set.

The instruction given in the Factory Service Manual (FSM) is to drill out the plug for a rebuild of the carb (Replacing a solid cap plug for the opening).

This means the carburetor can work without this plug.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation, just get a new carb.

Even when that carb was in production it would have been hard to get some parts, and now that it's 30 years old, it may be next to impossible. Getting a new carb on the other hand shouldn't be too hard (of course depending on you particular country and local). It is entirely possible that you'd have to get the part custom made if there aren't any around. But at this point you're going to spend a lot of time trying to fiddle with it and get it working again, and that time is probably worth more money than the cost of a carb.

If your lucky, you may be able to get an original carb from a junk yard, otherwise the internet is your best bet.

### Name of the plug

Based on [this patent](http://pdfpiw.uspto.gov/.piw?Docid=4234524&idkey=NONE&homeurl=http%3A%252F%252Fpatft.uspto.gov%252Fnetahtml%252FPTO%252Fpatimg.htm) that Aisan applied for in 1980, that would be called a "throw port plug." However that is per the patent, and may differ from how it would be named for marketing.

### Other Data

> This plug is to prevent adjustment of the idle jet for emissions reasons, which is factory set. The instructions in the Factory Service Manual are to drill out the plug for a rebuild of the carb (Replacing a cap plug for the opening). This means the carburetor can work without this plug as in many other carbs. (*Source:[Dumindu Mahawela](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/31310/dumindu-mahawela)*)

Comment: Please improve your helpful answer adding the following content . I will accept it. " This plug is to prevent adjustment of the idle jet for emissions reasons, which is factory set. The instructions in the Factory Service Manual are to drill out the plug for a rebuild of the carb (Replacing a cap plug for the opening). This means the carburetor can work without this plug as in many other carbs.".

Comment: Thanks. But please consider about controversial details of "replacing" and "ability to rebuild". Now the carb works fine after rebuild without this plug. I do like if this answer come under the heading of "Throw Port Plug"

Comment: @DuminduMahawela if you edit your original post to include that string (throw port plug) then this will show up under that search.